# WCF Service Can't Be Activated - Service Attribute Value

Tags: c#, wcf, http, service

I have the following service directive, in a project in Visual Studio 2012:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TMO.SA.VMS.Library.ServiceContracts.VMSService" %>
```

I can clearly see the TMO.SA.VMS.Library project, as well as the ServiceContracts folder and the actual c# service file. And yet I get the following error when I call the service:

```
The type 'TMO.SA.VMS.Library.ServiceContracts.VMSService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

I get this error from the test project:

```
The requested service, 'http://njpara-lp4306p5.gsm1900.org/TMO.SA.VMS.Service/VMSService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
```

My endpoint in the test project's app.config.

```
<endpoint address="http://njpara-lp4306p5.gsm1900.org/TMO.SA.VMS.Service/VMSService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IVMSService" contract="WCF_VMSService.IVMSService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IVMSService"/>
```

I am at my wits end, because I don't recall making any change to the service, or the way I call it. Any suggestions on what may be causing this are most welcome.

Comment: Have you tried including the assembly name in the Service attribute?

Comment: No. This worked at some point. Now it doesn't. I wonder what I might have changed, and forgotten about, that would now cause this.

Comment: Is the project reference correct and is the library getting copied to the bin of the web project correctly? Make sure that the library is being loaded correctly

Comment: You mean the reference to the service, that I'm calling from my test project? In any case, the endpoint I specify in the test project app.config file, the "http://njpara..." mentioned above, throws the error "The requested service..." also above. This used to work and I think it is still correct. If not, obviously this is a problem. But would something else perhaps throw this error? Something obscure?